# Upgrade to 5.38.1 seems to loose all my user created reports

Tags: upgrade, reports, custom-reports

Hi I'm testing upgrading to 5.38.1 and when I install ( even before database upgrade ) all my user created reports seem to have gone.

( user created reports - I means where they go in, copy a report, change filters and save the copy )

Obviously that isn't too useful - as there are a lot of custom reports.

Is there anything I can do - am I doing something wrong?

I'm just following the WordPress upgrade steps as documented.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because comes from a user error, not a real issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user issue not bug

Comment: I'm voting to close this as the author wants to, but I'm not sure this is the right action. I think the author can just delete the question and I would suggest that he does that as it doesn't really offer any value to anyone else. On the other hand he could accept his own answer to leave it in the answered state if he thinks it is useful to others. You may be confusing answered and closed.

Answer (score 1):

OK it seems that it is some issue with transferring to my test system  ( I myslqdump  and mysql ) and it seems there are constraints that are not allowed.  I did manage to get the transfer right once I completely trashed the dev database.  I'm assuming that the sequence of loading means it is checking against   'old' data.